# Isomorphisms between ordered groups

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Let $\mathcal{L}= \{c,R,f \}$ a language where $c$ is a constant symbol, $R$ is a binary relation symbol and $f$ is a binary function symbol.

Let denote $\Bbb{R}^+:=\{r\in \Bbb{R} : r > 0\}$ and $\Bbb{Q}^+:=\{q\in \Bbb{Q} : q > 0\}$

Prove the following:

1. $(\Bbb{R},0,<,+) \cong (\Bbb{R}^+,1,<,\cdot)$
2. $(\Bbb{Q},0,<,+) \ncong (\Bbb{Q}^+,1,<,\cdot)$

I think that for the first the exponential $h(x)=e^x$ is a isomorphism because it is biyective between both sets and it is increasing, so it preserves the order. Despite, I am getting stuck with the first, I guess it exists a formula which $\Bbb{Q}$ satisfies and $\Bbb{Q}^+$ not or viceversa, but I don't find it. Possible ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: There are rational numbers without rational square roots.

Comment: If the second isomophism would exist, then the automophisms of $\Bbb{Q}$ under addition would have in addition to the ordinary group structure under composition (which is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Q}$ under multiplication) a (possibly different) group structure via addition+isomorphism --- but offhand I can't think of why that leads to a contradiction.

Comment: Do these isomorphisms need to be continuous?

Comment: Expanding on Adamaszek’s comment, consider $\forall x\exists y\; y+y=x$, which is true for $(\mathbb{Q},0,<,+)$. Now translate it to your other structure.

Comment: The main thing is divisibility. An abelian or commutative group $(G,*)$ is divisible if for all $g\in G$ and all $n$ there exists an $h\in G$ such that $h*h*\dots*h$ ($n$ times) is equal to $g$. It is easy to verifty that $\mathbb{Q}$ with addition is divisible and the comments above mention that $\mathbb{Q}$ with multiplication is not. Note that the groups fail to be isomorphic as groups so they won't be isomorphic as ordered groups.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek thanks

Comment: @MichaelWeiss thanks, you are right :)

Comment: @Math_Images_Only yup, thanks